# React router is not redirecting based on condition

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am creating a school management system using ReactJS. In this I want to redirect the login page to dashboard when `isLoggedIn` props changes from false to true. From the console I make sure it is changing but I can't perform a conditional routing based on this props. Props is changing but not redirecting.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
...

class App extends Component {
  renderRoutes = () => {
    const { isLoggedIn } = this.props.auth
    return isLoggedIn ?
      <Redirect to='dashboard' /> :
      <Redirect to='/' />
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Authenticate} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardTeachers} />
          {this.renderRoutes()}
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to redirect to '/dashboard' after successful login and redirect to '/' after successful logout

Comment: how about checking isLoggedIn value inside componentDidMount() method and redirecting to dashboard?

Comment: Tried!! not working

Comment: are you sure that you're define dashboard route correctly? if so do debug and see is your desired values updates accordingly !

Comment: If I manually redirect it works. The problem is it is not redirecting

Comment: so inside your render method of loginComponent class you need to define redirect as this.
`if (isLoggedIn ) {
       return <Redirect to='/dashboard'/>;
     }
else{
return(//JSX of login)
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap private routes inside separate component and redirect from there.

Create a PrivateRoute component first:

```
function PrivateRoute({ auth, children, ...rest }) {
  const { isLoggedIn } = auth;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        isLoggedIn ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to="/login"
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Replace your code

```
<Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardTeachers} />
{this.renderRoutes()}
```

with this

```
<PrivateRoute auth={auth}>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardTeachers} />
</PrivateRoute>
```

And in your login component, redirect after successful authentication

```
if (!isLoggedIn) {
      return (
        // your login ui
      );
    }

// redirect to dashboard if login is false
return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
```